# Routing Error when trying to update Devise user details, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to fix issues with changing Devise user details in Rails 4 project. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827874/editing-user-details-creates-new-user-devise-rails-4) question

**Layout:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="user-profile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog log-modal">
                <div class="modal-content">

                        <%= render partial: "shared/profile" %>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**_profile partial.**

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password",:controller =>"users" } ,remote: true, format: :json) do |f|  %>


    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.text_field :name,:class=>"user-input form-control", :id=>"user-name" ,:placeholder=> "Lietotājvārds*",:"data-parsley-group"=>"f1" %>               
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">    
        <%= f.email_field :email ,:class=>"user-input form-control", :id=>"password",:placeholder=> "E-pasts *",:"data-parsley-group"=>"f2" %>                            
    </div>   

    <div class="form-group">                  
        <%= f.password_field :current_password, :autocomplete => "off"  ,:class=>"user-input form-control", :id=>"password",:placeholder=> "Vecā parole*                       ",:"data-parsley-group"=>"f3" %>  
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">                      
        <%= f.password_field :password , :class=>"user-input form-control", :id=>"password",:placeholder=> "Jaunā parole*                       vismaz 8 simboli ",  :"data-parsley-group"=>"f3" %>  
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">                        
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation , :class=>"user-input form-control", :id=>"password",:placeholder=> "Atkārtot paroli *                     vismaz 8 simboli ",  :"data-parsley-group"=>"f3" %>      
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="blue-button btn btn-default">Apstiprināt</button>
<%end%>
```

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'banned/index'

  get 'reusable/login'

  get 'reusable/registration'
  get 'reusable/password_recovery'
  resources :menus

    resources :blocked do
        collection do
           get 'checktoken'
           get 'checkemail'         
        end

        member do
            post 'toggle'
            post 'rev'
        end
      end

 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

     scope "(:locale)", :locale => /lv|ee|ru/ do         

       devise_for :users,  :controllers => {:registrations=> "registrations"}

        resource :user, only: [:edit] do
           collection do
             patch 'update_password'
           end
        end


        resources "successful-registration", :controller => :successful_registration, :as => :successful_registration


             resources :replies do
              member do
                put "like", to: "replies#upvote"
                put "dislike", to: "replies#downvote"
              end
            end
             resources :reviews do
              member do
                put "like", to: "reviews#upvote"
                put "dislike", to: "reviews#downvote"
                put "downwote", to: "reviews#complaints"
              end
            end

            resources :reports
            resources :offers
            resources :messages
            resources :feedbacks

           resources :girls do
                collection do
                   get 'checktoken'
                   get 'checkemail'

                end
                member do
                  put "like", to: "girls#upvote"
                  put "dislike", to: "girls#downvote"
                 post 'toggle'
                end
      end

      get 'sms/receive/', to: 'sms#receive'                      
      root 'girls#index'

      end

end
```

**Log file:**

```
Started POST "/ru/user/update_password" for 212.93.100.35 at 2015-10-03 14:08:12 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/ru/user/update_password"):
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
```

What I tried:

1) Restarted server
2) Tried to change order of the user routes.

I have no other ideas to try. Any help ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have routing for PATCH request (`patch 'update_password'`) but you are sending POST request.

Edit your routing file (`post 'update_password'`) or use PATCH request:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password",:controller =>"users",method: "patch" },remote: true, format: :json) do |f|  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer, you should also be considering [how `Devise` would provide you](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L50) with user account change functionality:

```
#  # Password routes for Recoverable, if User model has :recoverable configured
#      new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"new"}
#     edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"edit"}
#          user_password PUT    /users/password(.:format)         {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"update"}
#                        POST   /users/password(.:format)         {controller:"devise/passwords", action:"create"}
```

If you use `rake routes`, you'll see which `Devise` routes you have access to, and which you're able to use.

If you're looking to use `Devise` to handle this (which it appears you are), you can either use the above routes (which will become accessible if you add `:recoverable` to your `User` model `Devise` definitions), or if you call them directly.

If you want to add / edit `Devise` routes explicitly, you'll be able to do the following:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" } do
    patch   "passwords/update" => "passwords#update", :as => :password_update
end
```

--

I also see a lot of your routes being specifically defined. Although nothing wrong with this, it's very inefficient and actually prevents your app from being able to harness its true potential.

Here are some examples I would recommend you investigate:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :reusable, only: [] do
   collection do
      get :login
      get :registration
      get :password_recovery
   end
end
```

Another one is to [define multiple `resources` in one batch](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time)...

```
resources :reports, :offers, :messages, :feedbacks
```

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I would definitely try them.

Comment: No problem, always better to get your app working smoothly than to have it run slow